# How to make GPRS/EDGE/3G and wifi work at the same time on android

Tags: android, wifi, gprs

How can I code in my program to make EDGE/GPRS and wifi work together on android?

This can be quite useful; suppose i am connected to a server in LAN while i need to surf the web. A lot of my mates are eager for that, too.

Comment: did you get answer? I am also trying same thing. please help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if you can code your program to make it happen, but the link I stumbled on below shows how a persons phone could be made to have working 3G and wifi together:

http://mobisocial.stanford.edu/news/2011/03/let-wifi-and-3g-connection-work-together-by-hacking-connectivityservice-java/

Answer (score 0):

> How can I code in my program to make EDGE/GPRS and wifi work together on android?

This is not supported in the Android SDK, at least through Android 3.0.

Comment: @enzo: This is not supported by the NDK either. Custom firmware might be able to do something, at least on Android 2.2 and higher.

Comment: at least the cellphone is connected to GPRS and wifi while being an AP.